# sort two columns pandas like partitioning by SQL query

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, partitioning

I need to sort the values of two columns partition by partition as like what we have in SQL partition by.
In this example, I explain that I need it.

I have this data frame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [6,0,  4,2,  8, 2,  6,0, 4,8],
                   'B': range(0, 10),
                   'C': ['a', 'b','c', 'd', 'e','a', 'b','c', 'd', 'e']})
    A   B   C
0   6   0   a
1   0   1   b
2   4   2   c
3   2   3   d
4   8   4   e
--------------- partition by C
5   2   5   a
6   6   6   b
7   0   7   c
8   4   8   d
9   8   9   e
```

this is my final data frame :

```py
import pandas as pd
import random as rand
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [0, 2, 4, 6, 8,0, 2, 4, 6, 8],
                   'B': range(0, 10),
                   'C': ['a', 'b','c', 'd', 'e','a', 'b','c', 'd', 'e']})
A   B   C
0   0   0   a
1   2   1   b
2   4   2   c
3   6   3   d
4   8   4   e
--------------- partition by C
5   0   5   a
6   2   6   b
7   4   7   c
8   6   8   d
9   8   9   e
```

As you see I have a partition in the `C` column of data frame from `a` to `e` and I need to sort `A` column based on partitions on `C`. I couldn't find any good answer to solve it. This is something like Partition by in `SQL`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution, create a column `sort_` using [`GroupBy.cumcount`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html#pandas-core-groupby-groupby-cumcount) to identify partition & use [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html#pandas-dataframe-sort-values) to sort the dataframe by `sort_` & `A`.

```
print(
    df.assign(sort_ = df.groupby('C').cumcount()).sort_values(by=['sort_', 'A'])
        #.drop(columns=['sort_'])
)
```

---

```
   A  B  C  sort_
1  0  1  b      0
3  2  3  d      0
2  4  2  c      0
0  6  0  a      0
4  8  4  e      0
7  0  7  c      1
5  2  5  a      1
8  4  8  d      1
6  6  6  b      1
9  8  9  e      1
```